# How to share Persistence.xml between ejb module and web module in EAR?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, maven

We have one EAR application with one ejb module which contains all enity beans and few session beans and pojos. It has one persistence.xml. Now there is other web module which is spring mvc app and it uses entity beans in ejb modules. Now to use jpa I have to create one persistence.xml in web module too. But it is duplicated as we already have in ejb module. Is there any way I can keep only one persistence.xml in ear and will be used in both ejb and web module. Can somebody give me simple project structure as an example. Just for knowledge we are using maven.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can put your persistence.xml along with your entity classes into a separate jar that you put in the /lib folder of you EAR.

```
yourEar.ear
    |
    |_ yourEjb.jar
    |
    |_ yourWeb.war
    |
    |_ lib
        |
        |_ yourPersistence.jar
               |
               |_ META-INF/persistence.xml
               |
               |_ yourEntity.class
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But now my question is how does spring will know that where to look for entitymanagerfactory. I mean how can i declare a spring bean so that it will look for persistence unit already registered in jndi.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the exact question, but from my undertanding, you can declare a spring context in yourPersistence.jar and import it in contexts that are defined for your war and/or your EJB.

Comment: I figured out that I have to use <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="testPU" /> to use entity manager factory in jboss jndi context. But when I use the above bean declaration in spring 3 then it throws NameNotFoundException.

Comment: Can you post your persistence.xml file ?

Comment: please see the above comment for my persistence.xml and spring context.xml

Comment: When I share the persistence.xml via a child library, as you described it, my Glassfish doesn't recognize that my ejb uses JPA. When I place the persistence.xml inside my ejb, it recognized it. Can this behavior lead to a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample of my persistence.xml and applicationContext.xml

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

```
<persistence-unit name="acme" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/acmeDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="persistence-units/acmeManager"/>
         <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="persistence-units/acme"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And Spring context.xml

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence-units/acme" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty implementing this with Maven. If you will be using Maven to package your project, the following setting will put shared-between-ejb-and-web modules dependencies (anything in the ear's pom's dependencies defined as `<type>jar</type>`) in the /lib directory of your ear file:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib/</defaultLibBundleDir>
    …
</plugin>
```