# Specifying destination for dependencies in a Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jpa

In trying to see if this solution will work for my project, [How to share Persistence.xml between ejb module and web module in EAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589090/how-to-share-persistence-xml-between-ejb-module-and-web-module-in-ear)

I cannot figure out how Maven determines where it packages files in the output.

In my web project it places dependencies in /WEB-INF/lib. This is the right place, but I don't see it specified.

In my ear project it places dependencies in /. This is also the right place, but I also don't see it specified or know how to override it.

I would like my web, ejb, and other dependencies in my ear project to continue to go to /, but I'd like my jpa/domain jar to be placed in /lib.

I tried:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>copy</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <artifactItems>
              <artifactItem>
                <groupId>my.group.org</groupId>
                <artifactId>myJpaProject</artifactId>
                <type>jar</type>
                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
              </artifactItem>
            </artifactItems>
            <!-- other configurations here -->
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

But this put the jar in /target/lib/myJpaProject.jar while leaving it at / inside the ear file.

I hope that what I'm missing is obvious, but I just can't seem to find it readily in tutorials or documentation.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not part of Java EE 5 nor Java EE 6 standard. So what do you expect?

Comment: I just wanted to test the possibility given in the link above. Mostly I think I'm looking for the sort of control over packaging I had with build tools like gnu make -- how can I specify where I want a dependency to be packaged?

Comment: usually the packaging is done in the `target` folder and some temporary folder which is not relevant to run a build process. One point is very important. Maven is **NOT** Make. In the `target` folder you will find folders as ArtifactName-Version which contains the things.

Comment: So, doing the above I got myJpaProject.jar into the right target folder, but not in the right place in the jar, so I'm guessing phase=package is not before packaging, but perhaps just after. I'll try selecting an earlier phase to see if it'll appear in the new location in the jar. Maven is a build tool, so while it's not make or Ant, its development should be heading towards providing all the power and flexibility available from its competitors.

Answer (score 0):

The specific solution for putting shared libraries in the ear file under /lib is to set the defaultLibBundleDir tag for the maven-ear-plugin. It will place any dependencies of `<type>jar</type>` in the ear file's /lib directory.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib/</defaultLibBundleDir>
    …
</plugin>
```